# Azure Function App showing message Your app is currently in read only mode because you are running from a package file

Tags: azure-functions

I am doing [this azure function app tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-vs-code-csharp?tabs=in-process).

I am able [successfully run the function deployed on azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-vs-code-csharp?tabs=in-process#run-the-function-in-azure) as well

But when I browse the function on azure, I see this message

`Your app is currently in read only mode because you are running from a package file. To make any changes update the content in your zip file and WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE app setting`

[image: azure function app]

What is it saying?

[image: execute azure function app]

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 8):

Yes! When you deploy the function app to azure functions for the first time, it will show that message.

There are 2 steps to get rid out of that message:

**Step 1:** Modify your azure function code locally and **publish** it again to same function app. Refresh your function application in the azure portal and run your application now in the ***code+Test*** menu.

**Step 2:** Go to ***Azure Portal*** > Your ***Function*** App > ***Configuration*** (in the left index pane) > click on the `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE` in the ***Application Setting*** and make its value to `0` and click Ok and Save.
Restart your function app and go to ***code+test*** menu to run your application.

[image]

Comment: Didn't work for me, actually setting suggested by https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/run-functions-from-deployment-package asks to use: WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE=1

Comment: Hello @VivekDev, Keep the setting WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE=1 as it is! Update the Function App Code in your Local (VS Studio / VS Code) and republish/redeploy to the same Azure Function App, then that message goes out.

Comment: Option 1 doesn't seem to work, at least for me. Republished, refreshed, and still the message shows. Option 2 worked (thank you).

Comment: This solution is not working

Comment: Which solution not worked for you @none, as other users commented that option 2 worked in the above comments. What is your scenario and how you deployed to portal?

Comment: @HariKrishna changing the flag `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE` to `0` did not work it still stays at read-only. 
The only solution that worked for me is to upload the function with: 
`func azure functionapp publish $AZURE_APP_NAME --nozip  `

Comment: should `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE` be `0` or `1`?   `0` never appeared anywhere in the azure documentations....

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that worked for me was to re-upload my function again with:

```
functionapp publish $AZURE_APP_NAME --nozip
```

Comment: You can publish the Azure Function With/Without Zip Format Deploy. If You're using Visual Studio, you can publish using without Run from package (https://i.imgur.com/2ZhBcqu.png) also, you'll not get that notification (like `Your app is currently in read only mode because you are ...`).

Comment: @HariKrishna I am using VS Code to deploy `node.js` function, with the azure functions extension it is automatically deployed in a read-only mode, how can I change this?