# Azure function runtime integration doesn't work

Tags: python, azure-functions, azure-data-factory, azure-functions-runtime

I work on azure synapse and I want to use an Azure function to call python code (I search to list all sheet names from excel files).

However I don't understand how to run an azure function, I tried to follow some tutorials but none of them is precise enough when creating and integrating the function to use it in an azure synapse pipeline thereafter.

On my side I am blocked because it is impossible to run only one of my functions because of a runtime error message:

[image: The message when I wasn't to see my function in azure portal]

[image: The message when I go on my function apps]

I tried to change the default runtime but it’s been stuck on this message for last week.

[image: Another message when I change the default runtime]

Thank you so much for your help and time!

Answer (score 0):

**Please check if the below steps helps to work around:**

```
-The function runtime is unable to start.
- Unsupported runtime version: Your custom runtime version is not supported. As a result, runtime is being used.
- Cannot Upgrade with Existing Functions: Major version upgrades can introduce breaking changes to languages and bindings. When upgrading major versions of the runtime. consider a new function app and migrate your function to this new app.
```

***1. Make Sure you set your function runtime version to correct version number.***

***2. When migrating (upgrading/downgrading) the `FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION` (`Functions Runtime Version`), please check the code as it breaks the logic (syntax errors) because runtime versions are specific to the programming language versions also.***

For example, ***Azure Functions runtime 4.0 supports*** the following programming language versions:

- .NET 6.0 (in-process and isolated process)
- Node.js 14
- **Python 3.7, 3.8, 3.9**
- Java 8, 11
- PowerShell 7.0
- Custom handlers

**Visit the [Azure Functions runtime versions documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-versions?tabs=in-process%2Cv4&pivots=programming-language-csharp#levels-of-support) to know what changes have to made when migrating the `Functions Runtime Version`.**

***3. As discussed regarding this kind of error in the [GitHub-Azure-functions-host issues](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/5414), make sure you update the supporting language environments and their SDKs along with the code validation.***

***4. Check the Storage account is not deleted and exists for the associated function app.***

---

> Your app is currently in the read mode because you're running from a package file. To make any changes update the content in your zip file and webiste_run_from_package app setting.

**For the above error, please refer to one of my previous [workaround SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70046081/azure-function-app-showing-message-your-app-is-currently-in-read-only-mode-becau/70046169#70046169) and also the below step:**

***5. While publishing/deploying the function app to the Azure, unselect/uncheck the Run from package (file) option as shown below:***

[image]

**Also there is One of my other [practical workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71024448/change-the-default-folder-structure-in-azure-function-project-with-python) that shows you how to change the folder structure of the function app after publishing to the Azure Portal.**