# Getting error on Azure Portal when i try to deploy the app

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Getting below error when I try to deploy the app on Azure:
"Your app is currently in read only mode because you are running from a package file. To make any changes update the content in your zip file and WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE app setting."

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBMzh.png)

I have tried redeploying the application. Also, I don't have this variable "WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE" in my app configuration settings.

I have tried re-deploying the application and this variable "WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE" in my app configuration settings but nothing worked.

Comment: I found a similar question, and a valid resolution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/53632488/4317508, can you please have a look and see if this helps you?

Answer (score 0):

***Even I received the same error code as yours:-***

[image: Error]

I added the settings below in my ***environment variables of Function app*** and the error was resolved:-

**`WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE:0`** -

[image: Settings]
[image: Error-resolved]

**Reference:-**

[Azure Function App showing message Your app is currently in read only mode because you are running from a package file - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70046081/azure-function-app-showing-message-your-app-is-currently-in-read-only-mode-becau)